# Converting a nested JSON into csv with jq

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

I would like to convert the following JSON into a csv format using jq. I know there are tons of similar questions but I could not figure it out based on them.

```
{
    "one": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "gender": "man",
        "age": 32,
        "address": {
            "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "postalCode": "10021"
        }
    },
    "two": {
        "firstName": "Johnny",
        "lastName": "Smithy",
        "gender": "man",
        "age": 33,
        "address": {
            "streetAddress": "22 2nd Street",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "postalCode": "10021"
        }
    }
}
```

The output should look like the following. I'm struggeling with the nested object as value of the address key.

```
number,firstName,lastName,gender,age,streetAddress,city,state,postalCode
one,John, Smith,man, 32, 21 2nd Street, New York, NY, 10021
two, Johnny, Smith,man, 33, 22 2nd Street, New York, NY, 10021
```

The Best I could do is the foillowing but it does not come close...
Your help is much apreciated

```sh
jq --raw-output 'to_entries | map_values({ job: .key } + .value )'
```

Comment: Have you tried making an array out of scalars in each object and passing them to @csv filter? Like `jq -r 'keys[] as $k | [ $k ] + [ .[$k] | getpath(paths(scalars)) ] | @csv' file`

Comment: Thank you!  that looks very promising.  Do you know how I would also get the keys as a header row?  like that:
`
number,firstName,lastName,gender,age,streetAddress,city,state,postalCode
`

Comment: If it's constant, just pass it to the csv filter before everything else. Otherwise you can copy it from the first object

Comment: It will not be constant unfortunately, could you please show me how to do it in that case?

Answer (score 2):

For brevity, the following assumes that all the .address objects have the keys in the right order:

```
def headers: "number,firstName,lastName,gender,age,streetAddress,city,state,postalCode";

headers,
(to_entries[]
 | [.key,
    (.value 
     | (.firstName, .lastName, .gender, .age, .address[])) ]
 | join(",") )
```

Here, `headers`has been defined as a function so you can easily adapt it to yor needs, e.g.  if the header strings should be based on the key names. In that case, though, the detsils will depend on what assumptions if any can be made about the uniformity of the objects.